# How to scrape javascript injected image src and alt with phantom.js?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, headless-browser

I'm using the following script to scrape images using phantom.js:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
url = 'https://www.everlane.com/collections/mens-luxury-tees/products/mens-crew-antique'

page.open(url, function(status) {

if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('error');
    phantom.exit();
    return;
}

var a = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    });

SrcAlt = [];
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    var src = a[i].getAttribute('src');
    var alt = a[i].getAttribute('alt');
    SrcAlt.push({"src": src, "alt": alt});
}
console.log(SrcAlt);
phantom.exit();
});
```

But, the script hangs after I define the variable `a`, meaning it doesn't iterate through and return the src and alt attributes. When I `console.log(a)` it returns 34, so I believe I have the proper image resources. How can I access the src and alt information? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate your page after the page has finished loading. You can do this by using the `page.onLoadFinished` callback. This callback is called after all page content is finished loading and the document is ready. Something like this should work:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'https://www.everlane.com/collections/mens-luxury-tees/products/mens-crew-antique';

page.open(url);

page.onLoadFinished = function()
{
    var a = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    });

    SrcAlt = [];
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        var src = a[i].getAttribute('src');
        var alt = a[i].getAttribute('alt');
        SrcAlt.push({"src": src, "alt": alt});
    }

    console.log(SrcAlt);
    phantom.exit();
}
```